# build error Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET 2.0 Web Application which has full of .ASP(not .ASPX) and html files with 
 Jquery. I am seeing below error when I am trying to build the application in VS 2008

> Program 'C:\Work\Projects\Case\obj\Debug\Case.exe' does not contain a
>   static 'Main' method  suitable for an entry point

I checked build action for asp pages and they are set to "content" . Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Something's wrong here.  Look for a Program.cs file somewhere in your application.  Somehow you got a Console app in your web app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Web Application doesn't have `.exe` sort of things.
I think you have done a mistake while choosing the project. You might be choose console application instead of web application.

And console application required to `static Main()` function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // entry point
}
```

You can check the project property using

```
Right Click Project --> Application --> Output type
```

I think this should be console application in your case.

Comment: I chose ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: @user1358784 check output type in project properties under application section